# Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \begin{table} even with \begin{table}

Tags: tables, errors, booktabs

I have a host of errors telling me that I have missing items even though I can't find any that I have not included. This is occurring for figures, tables, floatingfigures, everything I have in the document. I have shown the issue with a simple table with most of my preamble in case I made any mistake there.

Errors Output from TexStudio:

```
line 13: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \begin{table}
line 13: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \begin{table}
line 13: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \begin{table}
line 22: You can't use `\hrule' here except with leaders. \caption{Some caption}
line 22: Missing number, treated as zero. \caption{Some caption}
line 22: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \caption{Some caption}
line 22: Missing \endgroup inserted. \caption{Some caption}
line 22: Missing \endgroup inserted. \caption{Some caption}
line 22: Missing \endgroup inserted. \caption{Some caption}
line 22: Missing } inserted. \caption{Some caption}
line 22: Undefined control sequence. \caption{Some caption}
line 22: Undefined control sequence. \caption{Some caption}
line 22: Undefined control sequence. \caption{Some caption}
line 22: Undefined control sequence. \caption{Some caption}
line 22: Extra \endgroup. \caption{Some caption}
line 24: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{table}
line 24: \begin{document} ended by \end{table}. \end{table}
line 24: Extra \endgroup. \end{table}
line 28: Extra \endgroup. \end{document}
line 28: Too many }'s. \end{document}
: Option "binary-units" has been removed in this(siunitx) release.
line 22: Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[margin=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,units,}
\usepackage[binary-units = true]{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath,caption}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{c c}
            \toprule
            Col1 & Col2 \\
            \midrule
            1 & Value of 1 \\
            2 & \num{4e10} \\
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Some caption}
        \label{table:demo_table}
    \end{table}

    My table \ref{table:demo_table} contains relevant data.

\end{document}
```

I have confirmed that my Latex installation is working by compiling an MWE from another question on this site using both TexStudio and JetBrains IDEA. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There appears to be an issue with `standalone`:  I've created a minimal document with `\documentclass{standalone}` `\begin{document}` `\section{foo}` `\end{document}` and get the same error.  Some tracing shows that it's happening whenever `\addpenalty` gets called inside a macro and `\ifvmode` is coming up false...

Comment: @leandriis Floats in standalone is supported according to the documentation (although by default they don't actually float), and as my comment above indicates, it's not actually a float issue.

Comment: @DonHosek: You're right. `float=false` is the default here. I misread the documentation and removed my misleading earlier comments.

Comment: @DonHosek standalone is an `\mbox` by default so it is a float issue in the sense that floats are not allowed in an hbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only look at the first error, later errors are usually spurious

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13     \begin{table}
                      [h!]
?
```

by default `standalone` processes the content in horizontal mode so it can measure the width, so this is like having a figure in an `\mbox` use the `varwidth` option to allow vertical constructs

Your document runs without error if you change the first line to

```
\documentclass[margin=2cm,varwidth]{standalone}
```